# matplotlib: Rescale axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, scaling

I've used [scale](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html) from `sklearn.preprocessing` to scale my data on the X and Y axis which compressed my data to `-2 < x < 2`. When I plot this data, I want the original scaling back for use on the tick marks.

My code looks like:

```
scale(readings_array, copy=False)
plt.plot(readings_array)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(0,24))
plt.ylabel("Total Traffic Volume")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.show()
```

Which looks like:

[image: plot]

What I really want is for the the xlabels to be 0->24 (0 at the smallest value) for hours of the day and the ylabels to be 0->600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first answer is: just keep a copy of your original data. Much the simplest, most pythonic answer.

```
scaled_array = scale(readings_array, copy=True)
# do stuff like learning with scaled_array
plt.plot(readings_array)
```

If you are trying to avoid making copies of your data. use `StandardScaler()` instead of `scale()`. You can either `inverse_transform()` the data when you are done using the scaled data:

```
scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler(copy=False)
readings_array = scaler.fit_transform( readings_array )
# do stuff with scaled data
readings_for_plotting = scaler.inverse_transform( readings_array )
```

or use the scaling factors to create x_ticks and x_ticklabels:

```
my_xtick_labels = np.arange(0,25)
my_xticks = (my_xticks*scaler.std_) + scaler.mean_
plt.set_xticks( my_xticks )
plt.set_xticklables( my_xtick_labels )
```

With my apologies for typos.

Comment: I used the first suggestion, so simple I love it!